# Bootstrap clearfix issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, clearfix

I'm a bit of a coding novice so would appreciate if someone could help me with a small clearfix issue on a bootstrap grid.

My grid is aligning perfectly for the lg, md, and sm presets but not for xs.

I want my xs to look exactly the same as sm. So 2 columns, 3 rows.

If someone could advise I would hugely appreciate it.

Thank you.

```css
<style type="text/css">
    */p{
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 32px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        background: #dbdfe5;
    }
    img.image-4-3.home-services-images {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  clear: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
    
    #spider2 {
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
        #spider7 {
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
        #spider9 {
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 0px) {
#spider2, #spider7, #spider9 {
            margin-top: 0px !important;
}
}
</style>
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Index</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
                            <div id="spider1" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> <img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
    <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
                            <div id="spider2" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
    <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                            <div id="spider3" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
    <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
                            <div id="spider4" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                            <div id="spider5" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" /></div>
                            <div id="spider6" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4">&nbsp;</div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                            <div id="spider7" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
    <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                            <div id="spider8" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
    <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
             <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                            <div id="spider9" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
    <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span></p></div>
            </div>
    </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the result:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

p {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #dbdfe5;
}
img.image-4-3.home-services-images {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  clear: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#spider2 {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
#spider7 {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
#spider9 {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 0px) {
  #spider2,
  #spider7,
  #spider9 {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div id="spider1" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
      <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="spider2" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
      <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs visible-sm"></div>
    
    <div id="spider3" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
      <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>
    
    <div id="spider4" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4"></div>
    
    <div id="spider5" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4">
      <img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="spider6" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4"></div>
    
    <div class="clearfix hidden-xs hidden-sm"></div>
    
    <div id="spider7" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
      <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs visible-sm"></div>
    
    <div id="spider8" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
      <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="spider9" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <img class="image-4-3 home-services-images" src="http://www.webconverters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/servicesCRO-medium-1.jpg" alt="Search Engine Optimisation" />
      <h3 class="Heading3" style="text-align: center;">Conversion Rate Optimisation</h3>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: 14px;">What would twice or three times as many conversions mean to you business? We continuously optimise your pages through testing and keep increasing your conversion rates, sales and leads. </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the XS breakpoints for Bootstrap, rows automatically force any contained divs into display:block and width:100% to help lay out the content vertically on a narrow mobile screen.

If you need to keep more than one column on mobile - then you will have to write a class to override the breakpoint behavior.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 nobreak-2col"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 nobreak-2col"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .nobreak-2col{
        display:inline !important;
        width: 50% !important;
    }
}
```